# Access service from one container to another container

Tags: docker

Couldn't find similar answer so posting the question.

Problem Statement: From my service container am trying to access | fetch details from vault which in running in another container, throwing connection refused error.

I tried with two approach to solve this problem:

1. **Using a Network-Bridge**

Steps:

- Created a network bridge `docker network create ayush_bridge`.
- Running the vault over the bridge `docker run --cap-add=IPC_LOCK -d --name=dev-vault --network=ayush_bridge -p 127.0.0.1:8202:8200 -v C:\DockerVault\data:/vault/data -e VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -e VAULT_DEV_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8200 hashicorp/vault server -dev`
- Now run the service using the bridge `docker run --network=ayush_bridge -p 8139:8139 -d --name=project_asyush ayush`

Error in the service container :

`Error fetching/updating secret from Vault: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8202`

2. **Using a Container Linking**

Steps:

- Running the vault service `docker run --cap-add=IPC_LOCK -d --name=dev-vault -p 127.0.0.1:8202:8200 -v C:\DockerVault\data:/vault/data -e VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -e VAULT_DEV_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8200 hashicorp/vault server -dev`
- Run the service `docker run --network=ayush_bridge -p 8139:8139 -d --name=project_asyush --link dev-vault:dev-vault ayush`

Error in the service container :

`Error fetching/updating secret from Vault: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8202`

But if I run the service with

1. `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8139:8139 -d --name=project_asyush ayush`
2. `docker run --cap-add=IPC_LOCK -p 8201:8200 -d --name=dev-vault -v C:\DockerVault\data:/vault/data -e VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -e VAULT_DEV_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8200 hashicorp/vault server -dev`

Then I am able to fetch the data from vault but I am unable to access the service end points.

What I am missing here ?

Comment: When you publish ports e.g. `-p 127.0.0.1:8202:8200` (==`--publish=8202:8200`) you expose the container port (`8200`) on the host (!) port (`8202`). From the host (!) you can then access the container on port `8202` **but** the container is running on port `8200`. When you connect containers using networks, you must reference the containers using the container (!) **not** the host ports, In both examples, the Vault container should be accessible through port `8200`.

Comment: I checked it, vault is not able to access I am getting "Error fetching/updating secret from Vault: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8200". Also tried from terminal to check if it accessible but getting the same error

Comment: I can't easily repro your setup. You may want to try `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1` too. `127.0.0.1` uses the localhost|loopback address and may not be accessible beyond the container.

Comment: The error message looks like your client is still configured to try to reach Vault on 127.0.0.1.  Even if the two containers are on the same network, or you're using the obsolete link option, the special localhost IPv4 address still refers to the current container.  You need to use the other container's name `dev-vault` as a host name, maybe setting the `VAULT_ADDR` environment variable.